# Connecting to Azure Subscription from Azure Pipeline without Service Connection

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-cli, serviceconnection

From Visual Studio Code or Windows Powershell, I can execute the required Az-Cli/Powershell commands and login to my Azure subscriptions without any problem whatsoever. I'm desperate to replicate this in my Azure Pipeline without the use of a Service Connection which isn't an option at the present time.

Unfortunately, Service Principals required to create our pipeline Service Connections can only be generated by a project team member who's currently unavailable, hence this not being an option on the table.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a service connection inorder to connect to azure subscription. You can use managed identity to create azure resource manager service connection to work with azure subscriptions.

Below [Azure documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-resource-manager-service-connection-to-a-vm-with-a-managed-service-identity) , can help you with different types to create a service connection in azure devops pipelines.

For information you can refer [this](https://stefanstranger.github.io/2019/03/02/ManageIdentityInServiceConnections/#:%7E:text=%20Steps%20to%20use%20a%20Service%20Connection%20with,Virtual%20Machine%20Identity%20on%20an%20already...%20More%20) blog on how to use Managed Identity Authentication for the Azure DevOps Connection Service.